# Remove whitespace in regex match

Tags: regex

I am using regex to read all the function names from the contract.
Example

```
(void) function_name1(int, int);
(void) function_name2(int, int);
(void) function_name3(int, int);
(void) function_name4(int, int);
```

output expected:

```
function_name1
function_name2
function_name3
function_name4
```

I am using Regex `"\)(.*?)\("`
With this expression i am grouping the function name with space in begining of the function.
Kindly help me how to ignore this space.

Comment: just put the space in the reg?!? `\) (.*?)\(`

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @ravi shankar does word 'function' change?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod Yes "function_name" I have given it as an example, in real code the function names are really different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
(\w+)\s*\([^()]*\)
```

see https://regex101.com/r/CzjFWt/1

```
<?php
$i = '(void) function_name1(int, int);
(void) function_name2(int, int);
(void) function_name3(int, int);
(void) function_name4(int, int);';

$r = '(\w_+)\s*\([^()]*\)';

preg_match_all('|' . $r . '|sm',
    $i,
    $o, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);



foreach($o[1] as $v)echo  $v;
```

result:

```
function_name1function_name2function_name3function_name4
```

or output the complete result array:

```
echo var_export($o[1]);
```

example in php:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3e387797e12853be040e00fcfd1d804629797b6

Result is:

```
array (
  0 => 'function_name1',
  1 => 'function_name2',
  2 => 'function_name3',
  3 => 'function_name4',
)
```

Comment: You can use this regex in a function. Almost every programming language has it. In PHP, for example, preg_replace. The areas in the parentheses are provided there as variables. In PHP the first e.g. in $ 1 
( http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php )

Comment: @Toto which programming language do you prefer?

Comment: <?php
$i = '(void) function_name1(int, int);
(void) function_name2(int, int);
(void) function_name3(int, int);
(void) function_name4(int, int);';

$r = '\b([\w_]+)\b\s*\([^()]*\)';

preg_match_all('|' . $r . '|sm',
    $i,
    $o, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    
echo var_export($o);
 <?php
$i = '(void) function_name1(int, int);
(void) function_name2(int, int);
(void) function_name3(int, int);
(void) function_name4(int, int);';

$r = '\b([\w_]+)\b\s*\([^()]*\)';

preg_match_all('|' . $r . '|sm',
    $i,
    $o, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    
echo var_export($o);

Comment: try it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3e387797e12853be040e00fcfd1d804629797b6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178923/discussion-between-sl5net-and-toto).

Comment: Sorry, my fault, it works. But you can simplify a bit: `[\w_]+` ==> `\w+` (underscore is already included in `\w`),  the word boundaries are useless (by definition, there are none arround `\w`). I gonna upvote :)

Comment: @Toto Thanks i simplified that.

Answer (score 1):

The `any space` (space, tab or linebreak) in regex is `\s` so you can use

```
\)\s*(.*?)\(
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and take group1

```
(?:\)\s*)(\w+)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uc8dom/2)

**Non-capturing group** `(?:\)\s)`

`\)` matches the character `)` literally (case sensitive)

`\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

**1st Capturing Group** `(\w+)`

`\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)